# ¿Cómo obtener dos filas de una sola fila en una consulta a MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla en MySQL que tiene la siguiente forma:

```
ID |  StartDate |   EndDate  | Value
---------------------------------------
01 | 01/01/2015 | 01/01/2016 | 100
```

Estoy usando este tabla para guardar datos para un gráfico creado en PHP. Lo único es que el gráfico necesita que los datos sean de esta forma:

```
Date       | Value
------------------
01/01/2015 | 0
01/01/2016 | 100
```

El `value` para el `StartDate` siempre va a ser 0, pero para el `EndDate` necesita ser el `Value` mencionado en la tabla.

Entonces lo que estoy queriendo crear es un *query* con clausura `WHERE ID =` que puede emitir los resultados en la forma de la segunda tabla. No hay problema en crear otra columna llamada por ejemplo `StartValue` donde se guarda el 0.

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Comment: Es decir, que quieres mostrar dos resultados para cada entrada en la tabla?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No indicas el tipo de agrupación que se requiere (ya que es de esperar múltiples valores para las mismas fechas), quizás sería mejor que aportaras el esquema real de tu tabla y ejemplos de carga junto con un resultado que esperarías. En cualquier caso, con una `UNION` se obtiene lo que indicas

```
SELECT  StartDate as Date, 0 as Value
FROM    TABLA
UNION
SELECT  EndDate as Date, Value
FROM    TABLA
```

Si deseas filtrar, filtra en ambas consultas

```
SELECT  StartDate as Date, 0 as Value
FROM    TABLA
WHERE   ID = ??
UNION
SELECT  EndDate as Date, Value
FROM    TABLA
WHERE   ID = ??
```